# What's the fastest (CPU time) way to get my current git branch?

Tags: git, fish

I'm trying to improve the performance of my fish prompt, and since my prompt includes my current git branch, I'm wondering if there may be a way to make it faster.

Right now I'm using `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed 's/refs\/heads\///'`, and when I first `cd` into a git repo, it sometimes hangs for a little while. I'm wondering if there is a known faster method, or how I could find out. Whenever I run `time git symbolic-ref HEAD`, it simply outputs `0.00 real`.

Comment: Run `strace -rtt -o git.strace git symbolic-ref HEAD` to see where it's spending time. Or `strace -f -rtt -o fish.strace 1234`, where 1234 is the PID of your shell, to see where the prompt setting is spending time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git symbolic-ref HEAD` is as far as I know the fastest method, it basically just opens `.git/HEAD` and some config files (`/etc/gitconfig`, `$HOME/.gitconfig` and `.git/config`). If you are sure that the delay is caused by the git command it is probably due to some io delay.

If you want a faster method you have to read `.git/HEAD` yourself but I doubt that it will make things faster.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I updated my question to reflect that I'm using `sed` to strip `refs/heads`. Is that likely to slow it down much?

Comment: @mybuddymichael i don't know fish but you should be able to strip the stuff from within your shell (at least with bash/zsh). Btw. what time region are we talking about? Multiple seconds?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it takes a few seconds to display my prompt after `cd`ing into a git repo.

Comment: @mybuddymichael is this a network file system or do you change into a subdirectory/have a big directory layout? git has to recursively change directories and check for the `.git/HEAD` file. Anyway best guess is some kind of io delay

Comment: Nope, this is simply `cd`ing into the top-level directory of a git project on my local drive. It's weird stuff, I know, but it only happens in git repos.

Comment: @mybuddymichael maybe low memory?

Comment: Hm, that's possible, I suppose.

Comment: Since your time command says it takes no time to run this, could the delay be part of setting the prompt?

Comment: For anyone else who's trying to further optimize their prompts (I was at 8-9% `parse_git_branch` in my zsh's `zprof`. Now I'm at 2-3%), one easy solution is to detect the common case of `"$PWD" = "$HOME"` and skip the call to `git symbolic-ref HEAD` altogether. It's a win-win since `$HOME` can't be a git repository and shells start out at `$HOME` when you open a new tab.